# Integrate Remote Desktop Client in a Web Page

Tags: cloud, html, rdp

I'm creating a cloud where clients can access same machine(Simultaneously Use same Virtual Machine)through RDP. Now I need some way for the clients to run the Remote Desktop Connection that comes preinstalled with Windows. I used a link to RDP clients location: `<a href="c:\windows\system32\mstsc.exe">`. But I was told it's not allowed because of security reasons and moreover it'll check for the location on the web page's hosting. So, now I am looking for way to Integrate the RDP client in web page.

Comment: you should look into Windows Terminal Services, especially the Web Access component.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the behavior of the RD Web Access role : either integrate the "MsRdpClientShell" activeX in your page, or make the user download a .RDP file.

Essentially, you are trying to do the same thing as the RDWA role. I suggest you look at the [RDWA role](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772452.aspx) for an example of how to do this.